# How do I test the significance of a distribution of tau coefficients?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, ranking, kendall-tau

I have (I think) a simple question. I estimated rank-orderings on a variable from a sample of 225 people, and I'm interested to know whether they generally correlated with a "correct" rank-ordering.

So I've computed Kendall's tau for the pairing of each participant's rank order with this correct rank-ordering. The distribution of the resulting coefficients is approximately normal... is there any reason I can't just perform a simple t-test to determine the significance of these correlations in aggregate? I can't see any reason why not, but if just feels too easy...

Comment: You first said that you computed ONE Kendall's tau. But then you talk about the "distribution of the resulting coefficients"... do you mean *multiple* values of Kendall's tau?  Please clarify.

Comment: What's your null here? Surely it's not that the correlation is 0 -- rejecting that won't tell you that they're 'generally correlated with a "correct" rank-ordering' in the sense that they're typically very alike, which is presumably what you're interested in.

Comment: @RachelAltman -- Yes, sorry. I've computed a Kendall's Tau for EACH participant, which compares their rank-ordering with one "correct" rank-ordering

Comment: @Glen_b uh oh... my null *is* that the correlation coefficient is zero? Truthfully I don't need to establish that the rank-orderings are very alike---only that there is any significant relationship at all

Comment: I seriously doubt that leads to any useful conclusion at all. For example, what value would there be in knowing there's an *extremely* weak correlation in rankings, other than it telling you that a blind ant could do almost as well?  Of course the rankings won't be perfectly random / unrelated to the "correct" ordering, so rejecting that is nigh pointless.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame this one was dismissed and left unanswered. Jonckheere (1954) and Stilson & Campbell (1962) independently proposed a significance test for the average Kendall's Tau against a "correct", or criterion ranking that seems to match the question perfectly.

A Kendall's Tau correlation between two separate rank-orderings can be transformed into the number of (dis)agreements on the relative ranking of each pair of objects (e.g. do both rankings agree object A is rated over B?), and forms the well-known Kendall's Tau distance, $\tau_D$ (a.k.a. the bubble sort distance).

$$\tau_D = \Bigg(\frac{1-\tau}{2}\Bigg)\tau_{Dmax}$$

Where $\tau_{D\text{max}} = k(k-1)/2$ and reflects the maximum number of possible disagreements (i.e. totally opposite rank-orderings), with $k$ objects being ranked. [I've provided another answer exploring this previously here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/531449/212847); transforming a Kendall's Tau correlation into Kendall's Tau distance is useful in this case because it underlies the null distribution used in the test.

If we calculate $\tau_D$ from the criterion rank-ordering for each independent rater, we can sum the total disagreements with bounds between $0$ and $n\tau_{D\text{max}}$ (i.e. all rank-orderings provided by the raters agree with the criterion, and all rank-orderings are exactly the opposite, respectively). Conceptually, this is the same as finding the average Kendall's Tau, and a relevant transform is provided below.

You can flip this by only counting *agreements* instead and come up with a similar measure if you're interested in quantifying how similar the rankings are to the criterion. The test proposed by Jonckheere basically defines a null distribution for the sum of total agreements for each ranking against a criterion ranking, defined as $P$.

The relationship between the average Kendall's Tau, $\bar{\tau}_c$ and $P$ is given by

$$P=\frac{nk(k-1)(\bar{\tau}_c+1)}{4}$$
Note that in Jonckheere and Stilson & Campbell compute this statistic directly, rather than calculating $\bar{\tau}_c$ as an intermediate step.

The distribution of $P$ under the null has a mean of

$$E(P)=\frac{nk(k-1)}{4}$$

and variance of
$$\text{Var}(P)=\frac{nk}{72}(k-1)(2k+5)$$
which can be used to create a test statistic
$$Z = \frac{P - (1/2)-E(P)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(P)}}$$
which follows a standard normal distribution.

In R you could implement this test like so:

```r
criterion_tau <- function(tau, n, k){

    # Null sampling distribution
    mean_null_dist <- (n*k*(k-1))/4
    var_null_dist <- ((n*k)/72)*(k-1)*(2*k+5)
    
    # Observed stat
    P <- (n*k*(k-1)*(tau+1))/4
    
    # Test statistics
    Z <- (P - (1/2)-mean_null_dist)/sqrt(var_null_dist)
    p_val <- 1 - pnorm(Z)

    res <- list(P, Z, p_val)
    return(res)
}
```

You can replicate the results in Jonckheere (1954) fairly easily. He analyses a dataset of errors made by learners in an experiment, and expects that as subjects complete more trials, they should make fewer errors.

```r
# Table 3 - Learning Experiment (Jonckheere 1954)
tab_3 <- matrix(
    c(0, 4, 10, 8, 5, 3, 12,
      2, 0, 7, 6, 8, 4, 5,
      1, 2, 9, 8, 5, 4, 10,
      0, 7, 5, 10, 6, 11, 9,
      4, 3, 8, 2, 9, 5, 7),
    nrow = 5, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE,
    dimnames = list(
        subject = 1:5,
        trial = 7:1)
)

# Calculate average Kendall's Tau
tau_vals <- apply(tab_3, 1, function(x) cor(x, 1:7, method = "kendall"))

# Run the test
criterion_tau(mean(tau_vals), 5, 7)
# Z = 2.42, p = .008
```

---

##### References

Jonckheere, A. R. (1954). A test of significance for the relation between m rankings AND k ranked categories. British Journal of Statistical Psychology.

Stilson, D. W., & Campbell, V. N. (1962). A note on calculating tau and average tau and on the sampling distribution of average tau with a criterion ranking. Journal of the American statistical association, 57(299), 567-571.